# R How to replicate nulls in a list

Tags: r, list, null, replicate

```
list(list(NULL,NULL),list(NULL,NULL))
```

The result is:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL
```

Supposing I want to do this for larger numbers than 2, is there a way to get the same list structure with replicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `replicate`

```
replicate(n=3, {replicate(n=3,NULL,simplify=FALSE)},simplify=FALSE)


[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[1]][[3]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL

[[2]][[3]]
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
NULL
```

Or more simplly (thanks @RichardScriven)

```
replicate(3, list(replicate(3, list(NULL))))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with fewer letters using `rep`:

```
rep(list(rep(list(NULL), 3)), 3)


[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
NULL

[[1]][[2]]
NULL

[[1]][[3]]
NULL


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
NULL

[[2]][[2]]
NULL

[[2]][[3]]
NULL


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
NULL

[[3]][[2]]
NULL

[[3]][[3]]
NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe write a little function so that you can adjust the replications and the length of each list, and also have the option to return an array or a list.

```
nest <- function(len = 1L, n = 1L, ...) {
    replicate(n, vector("list", len), ...)
}
nest()
nest(2)
nest(2, simplify = FALSE)
nest(3, 2, simplify = FALSE)
```